# How to cancel RestAngular promise .then()?

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

How to cancel RestAngular promise .then()? I am not sure how to cancel promise/xhr request in restangular/$http - it's fairly simple in jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can abort `$http` calls via the `timeout` config property, which can be a Promise, that aborts the request when resolved.

So in restangular, you can do this like

```
var abort = $q.defer();
Restangular.one('foos', 12345).withHttpConfig({timeout: abort.promise}).get();
abort.resolve();
```

Hope this helps!